# Show that $\vec{a}.\vec{b}+\vec{c}.\vec{d}\neq\vec{a}.\vec{c}+\vec{b}.\vec{d}$

Tags: vectors

Let $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c},\vec{d}$ are four distinct vectors satisfying  $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\vec{c}\times\vec{d}$ and $\vec{a}\times\vec{c}=\vec{b}\times\vec{d}$.Show that $\vec{a}.\vec{b}+\vec{c}.\vec{d}\neq\vec{a}.\vec{c}+\vec{b}.\vec{d}$

---

Since $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=\vec{c}\times\vec{d}$ and $\vec{a}\times\vec{c}=\vec{b}\times\vec{d}$
Dot multiplying the left side of the first equation by the left side of the second equation and the right side of the first equation by the right side of the second equation,we get
$(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}).(\vec{a}\times\vec{c})=(\vec{c}\times\vec{d}).(\vec{b}\times\vec{d})$
$(\vec{a}.\vec{a})(\vec{b}.\vec{c})-(\vec{b}.\vec{a})(\vec{a}.\vec{c})=(\vec{c}.\vec{b})(\vec{d}.\vec{d})-(\vec{d}.\vec{b})(\vec{c}.\vec{b})$
Now i am stuck and cant proceed further,please help me.Thanks.

---

EDIT 1:
As per the hint given by Michael in the comment below.If $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c},\vec{d}$ are all in the same plane,perpendicular to $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$
Let the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is $\theta_1$,the angle between $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ is $\theta_2$,the angle between $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{d}$ is $\theta_3$,the angle between $\vec{d}$ and $\vec{a}$ is $\theta_4$
$\vec{a}.\vec{b}+\vec{c}.\vec{d}=ab\cos\theta_1+cd\cos\theta_2.....(1)$
$\vec{a}.\vec{c}+\vec{b}.\vec{d}=ac\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)+bd\cos(\theta_2+\theta_3).....(2)$
But i am not able to prove them unequal.What should i do now?

Comment: $a,b,c,d$ are all in the plane perpendicular to $a\times b$.  Now it is a two-dimensional geometry problem.  Try using lengths and angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have to prove it's not true, one counter-example is enough. I constructed the following counter-example using the "most natural" cross-product between vectors (I have linked the calculations made with WolframAlpha):

$$(1,0,0)\times(0,1,0)=(0,0,1)$$

Use $\color{red}{\vec{a}=(1,0,0)}$, $\color{red}{\vec{b}=(0,1,0)}$. Now, rotate of $\pi/4$ rad:

[image]

And define $\color{blue}{\vec{c}=(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2,0)}$ and $\color{blue}{\vec{d}=(-\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2,0)}$.

We have $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=(0,0,1)=\vec{c}\times\vec{d}$ (check [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sqrt%282%29%2F2%2Csqrt%282%29%2F2%2C0%29x%28-sqrt%282%29%2F2%2Csqrt%282%29%2F2%2C0%29)).
We also have the required property [$\vec{a}\times\vec{c}=(0,0,\sqrt{2}/2)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2C0%2C0%29x%28sqrt%282%29%2F2%2Csqrt%282%29%2F2%2C0%29) and [$\vec{b}\times\vec{d}=(0,0,\sqrt{2}/2)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%280%2C1%2C0%29x%28-sqrt%282%29%2F2%2Csqrt%282%29%2F2%2C0%29).

But we have:

[$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+\vec{c}\cdot\vec{d}=0+0\neq \vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}+\vec{b}\cdot\vec{d}=\sqrt{2}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2C0%2C0%29.%28sqrt%282%29%2F2%2Csqrt%282%29%2F2%2C0%29%2B%280%2C1%2C0%29.%28-sqrt%282%29%2F2%2Csqrt%282%29%2F2%2C0%29)

Comment: Very good example,thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. However, I think you want to prove it is never true. My counter-example is not sufficient for this purpose. The counter-example shown above only says the equality does not hold but isn't enough, obviously, to prove that the equality never holds, which you tried to prove. I will think about it :)